# Transfer rows from one sheet to another starting with the second Column

Tags: excel, vba

I have a membership roster that I am keeping for a chapter in a club. Rather than delete members who are no longer in the chapter, I decided to try and create a macro that looks at the Chapter Roster Master sheet in column A (Still in Chapter?) for a "yes" value and then transfers the all the rows with the yes value to another sheet called "Chapter Roster Actual".

The macro works but I would like to only transfer columns B through O and not include Column A.

I realize the one line actually tells the macro to copy the "entire row" and I have tried to have it copy only a range but in doing that, it disregards the request to only copy rows where column A has a 'yes' value. I have the range line in there as well so you could see what I tried.

I also need to figure out how to not append the rows to previously copied rows. So, I guess it should clear the rows previously populated and then write the new rows.

Here is the macro:

```
Sub ActualRoster()
  Dim myRow, LastRow
  myworksheet = "Chapter Roster Master"
  LastRow = Sheets(myworksheet).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

  For myRow = 3 To LastRow
    If Sheets(myworksheet).Cells(myRow, "A").Value = "Yes" Then
      Sheets(myworksheet).Cells(myRow, "A").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Chapter Roster Actual").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
      'Sheets(myworksheet).Range("B3:O32").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Chapter Roster Actual").Range("A3:O32").End(xlUp).Offset(1)*
    End If
  Next myRow
End Sub
```

Comment: I'd suggest to use another variable to hold the next row no of the destination sheet and then use that for copying the row. If you want to use the range for copying, try applying the filter for the value yes and then copy the rows.

Comment: Sorry, could you please clarify. I am extremely new to this have created this from examples I have found in researching this capability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In what you tried, you are copying all the rows starting from 3 right upto 32 even if only current row is 'Yes'

The following works fine

```
Sub ActualRoster()
    Dim myRow, LastRow
    myworksheet = "Chapter Roster Master"
    Sheets("Chapter Roster Actual").Range("A3").CurrentRegion.Offset(2,0).ClearContents
    Sheets(myworksheet).Activate
    LastRow = Sheets(myworksheet).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For myRow = 3 To LastRow
        If Sheets(myworksheet).Cells(myRow, "A").Value = "Yes" Then

            Sheets(myworksheet).Range(Cells(myRow,"B"),Cells(myRow,"O")).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Chapter Roster Actual").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

        End If
    Next myRow
End Sub
```

As suggested in a comment, you can also try filter the Master data and copy all required data in one shot. As a starting point, record a macro and you will get a feel of how that can be done. Come back to refine recorded code.

Comment: Thank you but this produces a run time error. I recorded a macro but I am not sure how to record the function "if value in column A = yes then select the row. Recording the copying of the entire selection was pretty easy, so I did that and then tried to edit in some of the code from my previous macro, didn't have too much luck with that though. Thank you for your help I will plug away at this.

Comment: What is the runtime error that you are getting? This code is working fine for me. For clarity I have edited the answer to include full code. You can also insert a line to clear contents of 'Chapter Roster Actual' like in the code

Comment: Nice that it helped. You may consider marking answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code If you want to try using the filter instead of iterating over all the records. You can check which works best for you and use.

```
Sub ActualRoster()
    Dim myRow, LastRow
    myworksheet = "Chapter Roster Master"
    LastRow = Sheets(myworksheet).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Range("A2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlToRight)).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Yes"
    Range("A2").End(xlToLeft).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Chapter Roster Actual").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
End Sub
```

**Note:** There might be more optimized code for this scenario too
**Tip:** You can learn how macro works by opening the VBA along with Excel (in side by side mode), record the macro and observe the code generated.